# Build Solution on TFS using a specific changeset

Tags: tfs, build, version, changeset

I am developing a project that uses TFS to build solutions. But I found an error that I do not know how to solve it. When we compile a solution, we can specify a changeset to compile, right? Imagine the following scenario:

1. At this moment the last changeset is number C100
2. We created the proj file in TFS. After creating the file, the C101 is the last changeset.
3. I try to compile using the changeset number C99.
4. An error occurs: TF224003: An exception occurred on the build computer xxxxxxx: TF42006: The build service not could get the project build definition file is xxxxx. Ensure, the project file exists and the build service account domain \ xxxxx is a member of the Build ...

In this scenario, is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these suggestions?  Examine this scenario and see if any of it matches your case.
[possible solutions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/24cbc5e4-9a3d-4be1-861e-c639a1ed53cb)